# View SharedAccessBlobPolicy created programatically - in Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm creating a container and then a Shared Access Signature for that container in code as so:

```
 SharedAccessBlobPolicy policy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
 {
      Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write,
      SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(36)
 };

 var sas = container.GetSharedAccessSignature(policy, $@"{id}-{DateTime.Now}");
```

That work's fine.

However when I go into Azure portal I can't see a list of policies that have been created.

Does anyone know if this is possible and if so where/how?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Portal offers very limited functionality for managing Storage Accounts. As of today, this functionality doesn't exist there.

What you could do is use any Storage Explorer available in the market (including Microsoft's own Storage Explorer - http://storageexplorer.com) and view access policies there.

Comment: OK thanks. As I feared... no big deal I suppose but thanks for clearing up